# Run SQL query based on the previous output

Tags: sql

The following query results only "Operation is Success" whilst my aim is to run the "Select" statement listed under IF TRUE condition:

```
DECLARE @TOTAL int

Select @TOTAL = count(barcode) 
from domain_Media 
where ( (librarySlotNumber > -1) 
  AND (UPPER(volumePoolName) LIKE UPPER('scratch%')) 
  AND (id LIKE '05%' or id LIKE 'DX%') 
  AND (masterServerId = 17785613) )

IF (@TOTAL > 5)
BEGIN
  select * 
  from domain_Media 
  where (masterServerId = 17785613)
END
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is the returned total more than 5?

Comment: Yes, it's actually 16. I have even tried changing it to "less than 5", but it still returns the same result.

Comment: dbms name please?

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: sample data and output would help

Comment: Sybase SQL is the DBMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a single query?

```
select * 
from domain_Media 
where masterServerId = 17785613 and
      (select count(barcode) 
       from domain_Media 
       where librarySlotNumber > -1 and
             upper(volumePoolName) like upper('scratch%') and
             (id like '05%' or id like 'DX%') and
             masterServerId = 17785613
      ) > 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not condition the second query based on the first result?

```
DECLARE @TOTAL int 
Select @TOTAL = count(barcode) 
from domain_Media
where ( (librarySlotNumber > -1) 
  AND (UPPER(volumePoolName) LIKE UPPER('scratch%')) 
  AND (id LIKE '05%' or id LIKE 'DX%') 
  AND (masterServerId = 17785613) ) 

select * from domain_Media where (masterServerId = 17785613) AND  @TOTAL > 5
```

IT works in SQL Server